# Setting up an Eclipse CVS repo using a cloud service

Tags: eclipse, cvs, cloud-hosting

I am currently working on a project and realized it would be much more efficient if I utilized the CVS feature in Eclipse since I am working across 3 different computers in a given week. I have searched and searched but there is no simple set up walk through or best method approach on how to do this.

I want to utilize the CVS feature but have no clue what the best method would be. I don't have access to a server, so i have been looking into turning an old laptop into one, or using a cloud hosting site but have no clue how to begin. Is this even possible? If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Google for "cvs hosting" (Ignore the drug store). I recommend you host your source rather than have it on your machine if you care about it.

Once you have it hosted, install CVS into Eclipse (recent versions don't come with it anymore) and then follow the documentation in the Eclipse help. It's pretty straightforward.